# Appropriate loader in Webpack on Next JS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, webpack-html-loader

I want to load a HTML file with Next JS and html-loader, but I have this error message :

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

// next.config.js :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  env: {
    SERVICE_ID: process.env.SERVICE_ID,
  },
  webpack: {
    test: /\.(html)$/,
    use: {
      loader: "html-loader",
      options: {
        attrs: [":data-src"],
      },
    },
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

// My Component (Planning.jsx)

```
import Page from "../planning.html";

const Planning = () => {
  let htmlDoc = { __html: Page };

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlDoc} />;
};

export default Planning;
```

// planning.html

```
<div
  id="ID"
  data-id-projet="ID"
>
  Loading...
</div>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://reservation.elloha.com/Scripts/widget-loader.min.js?v=38"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var constellationWidgetUrlID =
    "https://reservation.elloha.com/Widget/BookingCalendar/ID";
  constellationTypeModuleID = 2;
  constellationBookingCalendarLoad(
    "ID"
  );
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem ? I really need to load some HTML code and JS script in my project.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using react.js, and you want to import html, you need to create component which returns proper `jsx` code. If the code inside `Planning.html` is what you show, that is wrong.

Next, syntax for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is like this

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlDoc }}
```

this is typescript definition

```
DOMAttributes<HTMLDivElement>.dangerouslySetInnerHTML?: {
    __html: string;
} | undefined
```

`htmlDoc` that you are passing should be string. For example, this `data` is a string

I think, if instead of `Planning.html` file, you set this

```
const data=`<>
  <div id="ID" data-id-projet="ID">
    Loading...
  </div>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://reservation.elloha.com/Scripts/widget-loader.min.js?v=38"
  ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var constellationWidgetUrlID =
    "https://reservation.elloha.com/Widget/BookingCalendar/ID";
    constellationTypeModuleID = 2; constellationBookingCalendarLoad( "ID" );
  </script>
</>;`
```

and then inject this

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I don't understand what should be a string exactly ? 

I have this error again : 

`./src/planning.html Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders > <div | id="ConstellationCalendarContainerID" | style="width: 100%; text-align: center"`

Comment: @SanB can you pls try the example that I posted on the answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you install [html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader) ?

If no, install it and try it again

Comment: Yes, I installed html-loader, maybe the configuration in my next.config.js is wrong ?